# JS: Odd errors when copying code from JSBin to live site

Tags: javascript

i was running some code in JSBin, following an online class.  i was running into errors, but, JSBin isn't exactly verbose.  so i copied the code into a simple HTML file on my local dev server... and got some very strange Type errors.  the code ran fine on JSBin, but borked when moved to the server.  can someone point out what the heck is going on?

here's the code:

```js
const suspectNames = [
  'Miss Scarlett',
  'Colonel Mustard',
  'Mrs. White',
  'Mr. Green',
  'Mrs. Peacock',
  'Professor Plum',
];
const suspectListForIn = [];
suspectNames.metaData = { provenInnocent: [] };

function createSuspect(name) {
  const colour = name.split(" ")[1];   <----------------------- works online, but not locally
  const speak = () => { console.log('My name is ${name}'); }
  return { name, colour, speak }
};

//  ADD SUSPECTS TO suspectListLoop

//  this is the class-taught answer
for (let i in suspectNames){           <----------------------- works locally, but not online
  let suspectName = suspectNames[i];
  console.log(suspectName);
  suspectListForIn.push(createSuspect(suspectName));
};
```

first, i get this error for `name.split` which worked fine online, but borks locally:

```
TypeError: name.split is not a function
```

second, i can't get the class-taught answer to run online, but it runs okay locally.  what the heck is going on??  i'm stumped.  :(

EDIT:
this is another proposed function using `map` but doesn't work for me again:

```js
//  another class-taught method doesn't work either online or locally
const suspectListMap = suspectNames.map(suspectName => {
   return createSuspect(suspectName);
});
console.log(suspectListMap);
```

EDIT2:
turns out while waiting for some excellent responses (thanks guys), i came up with a solution using `forEach1, which i instinctively wanted to use anyway.  it also had no problem with the`metaData` addition:

```js
suspectNames.forEach(element => suspectListLoop.push(createSuspect(element)));
console.log(suspectListLoop);
```

Comment: what's happening is that your `createSuspect` function is trying to be ran on your `suspectNames.metaData` property due to the behavior of `for...in` loops.

Comment: fair enough, i get that, but what i can't understand is why it worked for the instructor, throwing no errors, but craps the bed when i try it...  and i added another solution they suggested and, again, it doesn't work either for me, but does for the instructor.  this is the downside of video courses...can't ask questions!  :P

Comment: yeah, that's definitely a mystery. I wouldn't have expected the code to run, or perhaps something was mis-copied? who knows really, programming is full of shenanigans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, your issue is being derived from the behavior of `for...in` loops. It loops through the properties of the object, and your array of suspects has an extra, non-string property called `metaData`. The below code should function as expected for you. `for...of` loops are used to get the values (not keys or indexes) of iterable objects in JS.

```js
const suspectNames = [
  'Miss Scarlett',
  'Colonel Mustard',
  'Mrs. White',
  'Mr. Green',
  'Mrs. Peacock',
  'Professor Plum',
];
const suspectListForIn = [];
suspectNames.metaData = { provenInnocent: [] };

function createSuspect(name) {
  const colour = name.split(" ")[1];
  const speak = () => { console.log('My name is ${name}'); }
  return { name, colour, speak }
};

//  ADD SUSPECTS TO suspectListLoop

//  this is the class-taught answer
for (let suspectName of suspectNames){
  console.log(suspectName);
  suspectListForIn.push(createSuspect(suspectName));
}

console.log(suspectListForIn);
```

The next part is really just all style, and I'm just putting this out there for information's sake. I would personally move the code around a bit, and make use of some built-in functions available to arrays.

```js
const suspectNames = [
  'Miss Scarlett',
  'Colonel Mustard',
  'Mrs. White',
  'Mr. Green',
  'Mrs. Peacock',
  'Professor Plum',
];
const suspectListForIn = suspectNames.map(createSuspect);
suspectNames.metaData = {
  provenInnocent: []
};

function createSuspect(name) {
  const colour = name.split(" ")[1];
  const speak = () => {
    console.log('My name is ${name}');
  }
  return {
    name,
    colour,
    speak
  }
};

console.log(suspectListForIn);
```

The biggest change to this code is the removal of the `for` loop, and changing the initialization of `suspectListForIn` to be `suspectName.map(...)`. The Tl;Dr about the Map function for arrays is that it takes a function that will be given each individual item of the array as it's first argument. You can do some type of transform on that information, and return back a value that will be used as an element of a new array. [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a more thorough read-through. I use this, along with the fact that your `createSuspect` function returns a suspect object, to shorten the code by a good bit.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: interesting.  i wound up using `forEach` to solve the problem and it had no issue with the `metaData` at all.  worked beautifully.  i added it as Edit2 up top.  and by 'interesting', i meant it.  it's a new way of conceptualizing code for me.

Comment: the only questin i have at this point, is why `forEach` had no issue, but `map` and `for..in` did?